# Example of a continuous point on function with no RHS and LHS derivative?

Tags: calculus

I am reading smirnov's "A Course of Higher Mathematics" and Struggling with one of the example given below

[screenshot on the example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YEbAc.png)

There is no equation given for this curve but just the figure itself. Can anyone please explain this example in a more detailed manner ?

I understand that f(x) can be continuous for x = c but at the mean time not differentiable. But I just don't get this example here.

Comment: The idea is (for example) that $\lim_{h \to 0^{+}} (f(c+h)-f(c))/h$ will fail to exist because as $h$ approaches zero the slope measured by the difference quotient $(f(c+h)-f(c))/h$ will alternate between the slopes of the two given lines and never settle down. A higher resolution photo with more depicted oscillations might have made this clearer. $f$ given by $f(x) = x \sin(1/x)$ for $x$ nonzero and $f(0)=0$ has this kind of property; you can walk through the formulas and show it analytically even.. https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x+sin%281%2Fx%29+

Comment: As a side note, the community prefers that questions not include screenshots, for example, for accessibility reasons, and also because it demonstrates commitment to making a problem intelligible to others. I don't know what the guideline would be here, however, where the entire question is about a diagram for which no formula is given.

Comment: it doesn't help that the picture looks like it was drawn with a very thick pencil. :)

Comment: @leslietownes Yeah the book is really old.... but I just can't find an alternative covers the same scope of materials comparing with this one.

Comment: I understand. While I don't mean to stereotype, for some reason, large numbers of old books by Russian/USSR authors are of very high pedagogical quality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question asks about a depiction of an example of a continuous function which is claimed not to have left or right hand derivatives at a point $c$. The graph of $f$ is drawn as oscillating back and forth between two lines of different slopes that intersect at $c$ (where the value of $f(c)$ is the common value of the two lines) and one is to infer from the surrounding text that this oscillation continues indefinitely with the graph of $f$ as $x$ approaches $c$.

The behavior is analogous to the function $f$ given by $f(x) = x \sin(1/x)$ for nonzero $x$ and $f(0) = 0$.  (This function is continuous at $0$ because $|f(x)| \leq |x|$ holds for all $x$ and $f(0) = 0$.)  If you look at the graph of $f$ you can see that it oscillates between the graphs of the lines $y = x$ and $y = -x$ and it is possible to prove via formulas that there are sequences of values of $h$ going to $0$ from either side for which the limit of the difference quotient
$$
\frac{f(h) - f(0)}{h}
$$
is $1$ and $-1$, respectively, and hence the limit from either side does not exist.  (And note of course that $1$ and $-1$ are the actual slopes of the two lines $y = x$ and $y = -x$.)

Consider for example sequences $c_n$ and $d_n$ going to $\infty$ (or $-\infty$) for which $\sin(c_n) = 1$ and $\sin(d_n) = -1$ hold for all $n$, respectively (as can easily be constructed using the periodicity of the sine function; it's integer multiples of $2\pi$ plus either $\pi/2$ or $3\pi/2$) and then consider the values $h = 1/c_n$ or $1/d_n$ as desired.

Comment: Thank you, I alwasy thought the bell-shaped curve is finite, now it seems much more intuitive wth your example. It is kind of difficult to grasp a figure like this without any formula.

Comment: @user889162: *It is kind of difficult to grasp a figure like this without any formula.* --- Actually, the behavior is MUCH easier to conceptualize without formulas getting in the way. Also, instead of curvy ripples lying between the lines $y=x$ and $y=-x$ that squish down to the origin, we can have left and right saw-tooth patterns squishing into the origin so that each infinitely often touches both $y=x$ and $y=-x$ in every one-sided neighborhood of $x=0.$

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro I agree. A lot of examples of this type involve something resembling a "squeeze theorem" situation so the function will be guaranteed to be continuous, plus further noticing that you can do more or less anything between the "squeezing" functions and get the difference quotient (and/or neighboring values of the derivative) to be just about anything you'd like it to be as often as you want. Thanks for the insight.

Comment: For what it's worth, [pictures like this](https://media.springernature.com/original/springer-static/image/prt%3A978-0-387-74759-0%2F4/MediaObjects/978-0-387-74759-0_4_Part_Fig22_HTML.gif) can sometimes be found in older analysis texts (first half of the 1900s) in which Dini derivates are discussed, as a picture similar to that shown can easily show that given any extended real numbers $D_-, \;D_+, \;D^-,\; D^+$ such that $-\infty \leq D_- \leq D^- \leq +\infty$ and $-\infty \leq D_+ \leq D^+ \leq +\infty,$ there exists a continuous function **(continued)**

Comment: (indeed, real-analytic everywhere except at one point) that has these values for its Dini derivates at some specified point $(D_-$ is lower left derivate, $D^+$ is upper right derivate, etc.). (To get a specified infinite derivate, use an appropriate "square root" type boundary rather than a linear boundary.)