# Unilateral derivatives of arbitrary real function.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis

Unilateral derivatives are four Dini derivatives. There is a symmetry between them. I drew a picture which helps to memorize basic inequalities between them. $$A\rightarrow B$$ means $B\geq A$ and $$A\dashrightarrow B$$ means $B\geq A$ a.e.

*Picture for arbitrary real function:*

[image]

Also, I know two additional inequalities:

1. $D^+<+\infty$ and $D_->-\infty$ a.e.
2. $D_-<+\infty$ a.e.

I don't know how to add this information to the picture such that this would have some descriptive meaning. But I have other questions.

**Question 1:** Does this symmetry have some simple explanation? I know that we have $D^+\geq D_+$ because we take supremum and infimum on the same set. But I ask about other explanations. Can this symmetry be explained without using math? (By the velocity or other staff which we understand intuitively).

**Question 2:** What about relationship between $D^-$ and $D^+$? Can we say
$D^+\geq D^-$ or $D^+\geq D^-$ a.e.?

**Question 3:** In one book I saw "Upper derivative is $\geq$ Lower derivative (for arbitrary function)". Should it have been written there "Upper derivative is $\geq$ Lower derivative a.e."? By upper derivative, we mean the common value for $D^+$ and $D^-$.

> Let $F$ be defined in a neighborhood of $x_0$. We define the upper right Dini derivative $D^+F$ of $F$ at $x_0$ by $$D^+F\left(x_0\right)=\overline{\lim _{h\to 0^+}}\frac{F\left(x_0+h\right)-F\left(x_0\right)}{h}$$ We define the other three unilateral derivatives $D_+F,D^-F$ and $D_-F$ analogously.

Comment: *Unilateral derivatives are four Dini derivatives.* --- The term "unilateral derivative" nearly always (if not always) refers to an unspecified reference to the left derivative and the right derivative, and these will not exist (even infinitely) if the two Dini derivates on the appropriate side are equal. A unilateral derivative is also called a one-sided derivative. Even if infinite values are allowed, at most two unilateral derivatives can exist at a given point (exactly one exists is possible, and none exists is also possible).

Comment: *(comments of mine to [someone else's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4030535/13130) to a closed question, which is probably not visible to you)* For what it's worth, [pictures like this](https://media.springernature.com/original/springer-static/image/prt%3A978-0-387-74759-0%2F4/MediaObjects/978-0-387-74759-0_4_Part_Fig22_HTML.gif) can sometimes be found in older analysis texts (first half of the 1900s) in which Dini derivates are discussed, and a picture similar to that shown can easily show that given any extended real numbers $D_-,\,D_+,\,D^-,\,D^+$

Comment: I use the definition from A. Bruckner's "Differentiation of real functions". I added a picture.

Comment: such that $-\infty \leq D_- \leq D^- \leq +\infty$ and $-\infty \leq D_+ \leq D^+ \leq +\infty,$ there exists a continuous function (indeed, real-analytic everywhere except at one point) that has these $4$ values for its Dini derivates at some specified point $(D_-$ is lower left derivate, $D^+$ is upper right derivate, etc.). (To get a specified signed infinite derivate, use an appropriate "square root" type boundary rather than a linear boundary.)

Comment: *I use the definition from A. Bruckner's "Differentiation of real functions"* --- You're misreading something. Could you give the page and line numbers (or roughly indicate where in that page you are getting this impression about the phrase "unilateral derivative")?

Comment: Page 39. I added a picture also.

Comment: Page 39 (I assume the 1994 2nd edition) does not define "unilateral derivative". The 2nd sentence on that page is: "Four of these derivates are unilateral in nature and are called the Dini derivatives of $F$ at $x_0.$" By "these derivatives", Bruckner means the 4 Dini derivatives along with the upper and lower derivatives -- upper is $\max\{D^-,D^+\}$ and lower is $\min\{D_-,D_+\}.$ **(continued)**

Comment: He is saying that each of the 4 Dini derivatives is a one-sided notion -- "unilateral in nature" means that the mathematical formulation for each of these involves only one side, left or right, of the point. Note that the next (3rd) sentence on p. 39 is "The other two are bilateral in nature ...", and here he is is saying that the mathematical formulation for each of the upper and lower derivatives  involves both sides of the point. I do notice that he later says "We define the other three unilateral derivatives $D_+F,$ $D^-F$ and $D_-F$ analogously." **(continued)**

Comment: This later sentence can be confusing I think for a non-native speaker or someone (even a native speaker) who is reading this book without having studied Dini derivatives at all before. (Note that the book assumes familiarity with material in books such as Goffman **[80]**, Jeffery **[97]**, Natanson **[164]** -- see *Preliminaries* on p. 3.) In this later sentence "unilateral" is being used as an adjective, to indicate to the reader which 3 of the remaining 5 derivatives he means, and not as a noun, in the same way that one might say "... the two left-sided derivatives" for $D_-$ and $D^-.$

Comment: A nice overview of the Dini derivates is on pp. 119-126 of [**Introduction to Real Functions and Orthogonal Expansions**](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0195010744) by Sz.-Nagy (1965), if you can find a copy. See also pp. 149-170 in [**Functions of Real Variables**](https://www.amazon.com/dp/B00085GID0) by Townsend (1928) and pp. 333-334 of [Hobson's book](https://archive.org/details/theoryfunctreal01hobsrich/page/n353/mode/2up) (better if can find the 3rd edition). Best of all, I recommend beginning by going through [**A Primer of Real Functions**](https://www.amazon.com/dp/088385029X) by Boas.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro I thought I had found the absolut thuth :). Thanks! I will rethink what you write. One little additional question( need an advice from an experienced person) : does one who wants to go deeper in harmonic analysis have to know all this staff from A. Bruckner's book?

Comment: I will start with Boas. Thank you for references!

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro: I mean 1) is there a need to go so deep as in A.Bruckner's book and 2) if there is not a need then can I expect that this staff from Bruckner will give me deeper understanding?

Comment: I would start with Boas's book and then see where your interests lie. As for specifics about Dini derivatives, the [Denjoy-Young-Saks theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denjoy%E2%80%93Young%E2%80%93Saks_theorem) is probably the most significant result. Worth looking at is pp. 344-348 of [this paper about G. C. Young and W. H. Young](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82124377.pdf) and [*Analogues of the Denjoy-Young-Saks theorem*](https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1982-271-01/S0002-9947-1982-0648091-0/) by Belna/Cargo/Evans/Humke (1982).

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro I will write when I finish this book!

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro: I have finished Boas's book. I "knew" everything in this book but had not understanding as I have now. Thanks! It is a great book! What do you recomend to read after this?

Comment: I recommend [**A Second Course on Real Functions**](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0521283612) by van Rooij/Schikhof (1982) *AND* [**The Integrals of Lebesgue, Denjoy, Perron, and Henstock**](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0821838059) by Gordon (1994; first 7 chapters mostly) *AND* [**Advanced Analysis on the Real Line**](https://www.amazon.com/dp/038794642X) by Kannan/Krueger (1996). Probably the book by Gordon is best if your primary goal is to get an appropriate background for Bruckner's book.

Comment: I noticed you mentioned harmonic analysis earlier, which I did not realize until now. Given that, you probably don't want to keep digging deeper into this classical real analysis stuff (e.g. into Bruckner's book), but I'd still recommend the first 7 chapters of Gordon's book, and having the two other books on your bookshelf might be useful (if you have the money to get them). However, unless you find you really like this material, I'd recommend later looking at [**Measure Theory and Fine Properties of Functions**](https://www.amazon.com/dp/1482242389) by Evans/Gariepy (2015, 2nd edition).

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro Hello! I have finished two books which you recomend me to read. I have read "Measure Theory and Fine Properties of Functions". Also I have read Baos. Your recomendations are very usefull. Thank you! In your opinion what next book would be better? I am interested in harmonic analysis. Two books mentioned above are not on harmonic analysis. But they help me a lot to understand things. Please say what book can help me to improve my understanding futher?

Comment: At this point you know a lot more about the topics that closely relate to harmonic analysis than I do. Maybe the answers/comments in this question will help: [Learning roadmap for harmonic analysis](https://mathoverflow.net/q/66801/15780) That said, [**Singular Integrals and Differentiability Properties of Functions**](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0691080798) by Elias M. Stein (1971) seems to be a reasonable choice based on your interests and background thus far. Stein also has a couple of other books worth considering -- see "Customers who viewed this item also viewed" at the amazon.com page.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro Thank you for the links!